# How can I disable tooltips during selection?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to disable Highcharts tooltip on selection?
I tried:

```
...
charts: {
    events: {
        selection: function(event) {
             this.tooltip.enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I do want the tooltip the behave normally whenever a user simply hovers over the data.
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "selection" here? Do you mean selecting a point (`allowPointSelect`-series), or zooming (`zoomType`-chart)?

Comment: @HalvorHolstenStrand, I use the `zoomType`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `selection` event is fired only after an area of the chart has been selected. You can use `mousedown` and `mouseup` events on a chart container to toggle a tooltip:

```
chart: {
    zoomType: 'x',
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var chart = this,
                chartContainer = document.getElementById('container');

            chartContainer.onmousedown = function(e) {
                chart.update({
                    tooltip: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                });
            };

            chartContainer.onmouseup = function() {
                chart.update({
                    tooltip: {
                        enabled: true
                    }
                });
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y0fLuk9a/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#update

Comment: Nice! it's roughly the approach I was trying. However, a user may load various dashboards that may contain many different charts. Is there a "Highcharts" way to identify the chart within the oprions?

Comment: Hi @DSCH, Do you mean the chart container? Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4L3stx1z/